# How to save class as one of the attributes in ROR model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a model in rails named chat, where I have two columns user1 and user2, and I want to store the user object in these. In grails, I do this simply as

```
class Chat {
  User user1
  User user2
  Date chatStartedOn
}
```

and I am done. I did somewhat the same for rails

```
rails generate model Chat user1:User user2:User chatStartedOn:date
```

but I run db:migrate it showing me the error

```
undefined method `User' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition
```

my user migrate file

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username 
      t.string :email
      t.string :encrypted_password 
      t.string :salt
      t.timestamps
    end
  end 
end
```

Please guide me on how I save user's object in chat table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
rails generate migration CreateChats
```

You can then add this code in your Chat migration file

```
class CreateChats < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :chats do |t|
      t.integer :user1_id,  :references => [:users, :id]
      t.integer :user2_id,  :references => [:users, :id]
      t.date :chatStartedOn
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

you would then need to add the associations

Model user.rb

```
has_one :chat
```

Model chat.rb

```
belongs_to :user1, :class_name => "User"

belongs_to :user2, :class_name => "User"
```

Comment: i m getting this error i followed all wht u mentioned ..." rake aborted !. Mysql2::Error: Table 'databaseName.user1' doesn't exist:"

Comment: Note that rails follows a naming convention and hence in the chat model we do not need to specify the foreign key database field name..Since my association is set to user1 the foreign key is assumed to be user1_id